# Cannot access autospawn lock Debian

Tags: docker, debian, mounted-volumes, automount, obsidian

I followed a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/_sfddZHhOj4) that helped me setup a Proxmox/Truenas/Docker server. It has you create a share drive on the Truenas VM and then automount it to the Docker VM. I then tried to install a Docker App for [Obsidian](https://github.com/sytone/obsidian-remote) and had this error:

> E: [autospawn] core-util.c: Failed to symlink /config/.config/pulse/fdcd261a83bb46b7ae984385e3448e98-runtime to /tmp/pulse-FwqVeKeiSoJO: Operation not supported
> W: [autospawn] lock-autospawn.c: Cannot access autospawn lock.
> E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock

On doing further research, I've found that it's probably caused by the automount system I'm using. I'm using /etc/fstab. I don't have access to the line of code that I used at this moment, but when I do I will update this or put it in a comment.

Does anyone have any ideas what I need to do in order to get it to work?

I've tried a couple solutions, but most of them were before I found out about the issue with the mounting. I have not been able to find any solutions or similar problems so I haven't been able to try much.